# How to log in and log out user, before running tests

Tags: javascript, cypress

In Cypress I'm trying to test something in a backend. I'm really struggling to control if the user is logged in or not.

I'm trying to automate all testing that i do, when developing features. I spend so much time and effort to control if the user is logged in or not.

I'm looking for a command that does this:

1. Logout any user (if one is logged in), when starting any test.
2. A fast way to do something like: `cy.loginUser( 'foo@example.org', 'password' )`?

Since this will have to run before many of the tests, if would be nice to streamline it.

It's being used on a Laravel / Vue application (hence the CSRF-token).

### My current attempt:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add( "loginUser", ( email, password ) => {
  cy.server();
  
  // Source: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/413
  sessionStorage.clear();
  cy.clearCookies();
  cy.clearLocalStorage();
  cy.window().then((win) => {
  win.sessionStorage.clear()
  });
  
  cy.visit( Cypress.env( 'baseUrl' ) + "/login");
  
  cy.location().should((loc) => {
    expect(loc.pathname).to.eq('/login')
  });
  
  cy.get("head meta[name=csrf-token]")
    .then((meta) => {
    const csrf = meta[0].content;
  
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/login',
      body: {
        _token: csrf,
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
    });
  });
  
  cy.visit( Cypress.env( 'baseUrl' ) + "/login");
});
```

The problems with this:

- For some wierd reason... Every second time, the user remains logged in from the previous session. But if that happens, then I simply have to run it again, - and then the user is logged out. It's driving me bananas.
- It's not slow, - but it's not fast either (considering that I do it a bazillion times). So if it could be done faster (with less page loads), then it would be smashing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another way to clear localStorage. For example, I'm using these commands to save, restore and clear storage and is working perfect. I'm using these for log in/log out things.

```
let LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY = {};

Cypress.Commands.add("saveLocalStorage", () => {
  Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
    LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key] = localStorage[key];
  });
});

Cypress.Commands.add("restoreLocalStorage", () => {
  Object.keys(LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY).forEach(key => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key]);
  });
});

Cypress.Commands.add("clearLocalStorageCache", () => {
  localStorage.clear();
  LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY = {};
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but without any other result. Thanks for weighing in, though.